# Linked Lists. Head and Tail References

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Im trying to make an Add and Delete method to my linked list class. I made 2 references with the names Head and Tail.

Head -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> Tail:null

I keep getting problems when I try and delete specific nodes because Java says I'm out of bounds. I think it is because my Head isn't pointing to the first Node? What do you guys think? Or am i going about this the total wrong way...

```
public class LinkedList{

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int listCount;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = new ListNode(null);
        tail = new ListNode(null);
        listCount = 0;
    }

    public void add(Object elem){
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(elem);
        if (size() == 0){
            newNode = head;
            tail = head;
        }
        newNode.setLink(tail);
        tail = newNode;
        listCount++;
        }

    public Object delete(int index)
    // post: removes the element at the specified position in this list.
    {
        // if the index is out of range, exit
        if(index < 1 || index > size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        ListNode current = head;
        for(int i = 1; i < index; i++)
        {
            if(current.getLink() == null)
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

            current = current.getLink();
        }
        current.setLink(current.getLink().getLink());
        listCount--; // decrement the number of elements variable
        return current.getInfo();
    }

    public int size() {
        return listCount;
    }

}

public class Node {

    private Node link;
    private Object info;

    public Node(Object info)
    {
        this.info = info;
        link = null;
    }

    public void setInfo(Object info)
    {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public Object getInfo()
    {
        return info;
    }

    public void setLink(Node link)
    {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public Node getLink()
    {
        return link;
    }
}
```

Comment: A wild guess here, but `newNode.setLink(tail)` should be the other way around?

Comment: @webuster Im not sure what you mean, could you elaborate a little more? Thanks appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you did not initialize the link from head to tail when you set up your initial (empty) linked list.

Ok.  Here is a strategy to use when working with singly linked lists (forward link only). You need to determine what actions will be allowed on the list (e.g. add/remove from head or tail only?; or add and remove nodes anywhere in the linked list (bringing the list back together once you have cut a node out). If you will be allowing nodes to be deleted from anywhere, then you will need to have a way of UNIQUELY identifying each node (so you can unambiguously determine the node that will be deleted).  You may also want to be able to add a node before or after some other node . and uniqueness may be needed for that.  If you do NOT care which value you delete or add before/after then you can relax the uniqueness constraint.

Now for strategy to implement. Start with a head (initially null).

1. **To add a node**, walk down your linked list until you find a null next link. Replace that with your node, and have your nodes forward link set to null.  (Efficiency improvement, have a tail that always has the last node in the linked list, or null if there is nothing in the list).
2. **To delete a node**, walk your list until you find the node you want to delete, change the previous link to the link in the node to be deleted (you are now done)
3. **To add a node at the end** of the list, go to the link pointed to by tail (if null, list is emplty); change its link to your node, ensure your new node has a null in its link; and set the tail to your node
4. **To count size** of linked list, either walk your tree and count (or, for computational efficiency, keep a running size that is incremented or decremented when you add or delete a node.

Does this help?

Look [at this link for a full description](http://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/ccb98/teaching/ee2_software_engineering/Lecture4-LinkedLists.pdf)!

Comment: Yea thats what I thought! Im teaching Linked Lists to myself so its hard to grasp the concept. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because your `head` never links to anything. What I would do to fix it is in your add method, check the `size` of your list; if it's 0, set the head to the new element and set the `tail` equal to the `head`. If it's 1, link the `head` to the new node and set `tail`. If it's 2, just set the `tail`'s link to the new node and set the `tail` (like you have now).

Also, I'm not sure how you implemented it, but `newNode.setLink(tail);` seems wrong...the `tail` should be linked to `newNode`. From the way it looks, it seems like you're trying to do newNode -> tail

EDIT: Ok, here is why I would try

```
public void add(Object elem){
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(elem);
    if (size() == 0){
        newNode = head;
        tail = head;
    }else if(size() == 1){
        head.setLink(newNode);
        tail = newNode;
    }else{
        tail.setLink(newNode);
        tail = newNode;
    }
    listCount++;
}
```

Comment: Ok I think I get it...maybe haha!

Comment: try it and see if it works. If not, just edit your question with your new code.

Comment: post your entire LinkedList class in the OP

Comment: @Bob can you post your setLink method? I just want to see it.

Comment: I did. Its under the Node Class :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48091/discussion-between-bob-and-embattled-swag)